# HTML 5 showing up locally but not on testing server in IE 9

Tags: html

I built a soon to be site and uploaded to my testing server, not working in IE 9 or any other version of IE works fine in Mozilla and Chrome. The Strange thing is it works on IE 9 on my computer.
Any help would be appreciated.

The testing server is http://webpages.charter.net/jpetree/cctest

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

Move your conditional comment for the shiv down into the head where it belongs and try that.

Comment: done but to no avail, displaying in the right position but I'm using the rgba color space and it's not displaying the blocks. Just curious if this may be something in the css3.